# Oracle ORA_ROWSCN is null after Upgrade to Oracle 11

Tags: oracle

After upgrading from Oracle 10 to Oracle 11 we are finding that ORA_ROWSCN is intermittently showing as NULL on tables where rowdependencies was enabled prior to the upgrade.

I am aware that this is normal prior to a commit, but we are fining this is true after an update is committed as well.

Updating the row by setting(eg) id = id will reset the ORA_ROWS so it appear as non-null.

Has anyone else experienced this..?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a bug in oracle.. check this [link](http://sai-oracle.blogspot.com/2010/05/all-about-orarowscn.html).. point#3